# Java method doesn't change parameter objects

Tags: java, object, parameters, pass-by-reference

I have a function like this:

```
public static int partition(List list, ListElement elemL, ListElement elemR){
    ListElement elemX;
    ...
    elemR = elemX.next;
    return x; 
}
```

And at the end of the funktion the *elemR* is changed, but after calling the function from the main method the parameter *elemR* has still the same value like before the function call.
What's the problem? How can i change this ListElement and "save" this change after the function is called without changing the return type to ListElement (i need the integer return value too)?

Comment: Java isn't call by reference it is only call by value. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: what do you mean with "make the method destructive"? how to do that?

Comment: This example may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607773/change-a-functions-arguments-values

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem
But I still have no idea how to fix this problem, because I'm note able to change the value of elemX, I have to allocate another object to elemR. Does anybody have an idea, how to do this?

Comment: OK, I think I just found a solution.
I put the elemR and elemL in a ArrayList and put the ArrayList as parameter in the function, so it seems to work successful (:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java functions parameters are called by reference name, meaning that when you place an object as an function argument, the JVM copies the reference's value to a new variable, and passes it to the function as an argument. 
If you change the contents of the object, then the original object will change, but if you change the actual value of the reference, then these changes will be destroyed when the function ends.

I hope it helps